# How to do this mouse over effect in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover

i have a question that i'm struggling with it for a couple of days but i could'nt find a right answer. I want to have a mouseover effect like the one in this template (that buddha in top of page). I tried many ways but I couldnt get the one that i wanted, and i am in a hurry too. Can anyone tell me what to do? thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
      <style>
        .mybtn{
            color: white;
            padding:10px;
            border-style: none;
        }
        .myhover{
          background-color: #555;
          transition: background-color 0.4s;
        }
          .myhover:hover{
          background-color: teal;
        }
    </style>

   <button class="mybtn myhover">Hover me!</button>
```